# Numeric column to datetime in SQL

Tags: mysql, date

I have a numeric column in my 'daily call' dataset which has a numeric format that I would like to convert into a DATE format.

The problem is, the column has a single data of '81121' (INT) which basically should convert to Aug 11, 2021. however when I use DATE(column name), it converts it to Nov 21, 2008 (CAST gives me the same result).

I have tried CONVERT as well but no luck.

Can someone please advise?

Note: The '11' part in 81121 is the date which changes everyday (looking for something scalable)

Regards,
S

Comment: How do you interpret 11121? Is it January 11 21 or November 1 21?

Comment: 1 - January , 11 - Date, 21 - Year i.e. Jan 11th, 2021

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```sql
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(LPAD(81121, 6, '0'), '%m%d%y')

-- note that %m expects 2 digits so LPAD is necessary
```

However I would suggest storing dates using the `date` datatype.